# php MySql error null given

Tags: php, mysql, null, warnings

I have this code:

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM maintable;";
mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($link));
$i = 0;
do{
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo '<p>'.$row["Description"].'</p>';
     $i++;
}while($row && $i<10);
```

and `or die` does not print any errors, but it is still not working and gives me messege:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given

Comment: `$result` is undefined in this code. You should set it to the result of `mysqli_query` before passing it into `mysqli_fetch_array`.

Comment: thanks man I just forgot about it, was searching for mistake for long and it was as simple as that!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM maintable;";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($link));
$i = 0;
do{
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo '<p>'.$row["Description"].'</p>';
 $i++;
}while($row && $i<10);
```